# How to do bitwise compare of two hex strings?

Tags: perl, hex, bitwise-operators

I have two strings representing hex numbers which I need to make a bitwise comparison of.  Each hex number equates to 256 bits.  I need to determine how many of the bits are different.  How can I do this in `perl`?

```
$hash1 = "7ff005f88270898ec31359b9ca80213165a318f149267e4c2f292a00e216e4ef";
$hash2 = "3fb40df88a78890e815251b1fb8021356da330f149266f453f292a11e216e4ee";
```

My question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286901/compare-two-hex-strings-to-find-number-of-matching-bits) but I need to do it in `perl`.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $bytes1 = pack('H*', $hash1);
my $bytes2 = pack('H*', $hash2);
my $xor    = unpack('B*', $bytes1 ^ $bytes2);
my $count  = $xor =~ tr/1//;
```

[`pack('H*', ...)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) converts the hex strings into byte strings. The byte strings are then XORed and converted to a bit string with `unpack('B*', ...)`. The `tr` operator is used to count the number of 1s (different bits) in the bit string.

Or, using the [checksum trick described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046822/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-count-number-of-set-bits-in-binary-file):

```
my $bytes1 = pack('H*', $hash1);
my $bytes2 = pack('H*', $hash2);
my $count  = unpack('%32B*', $bytes1 ^ $bytes2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$hash1 =~ s/([a-f0-9][a-f0-9])/unpack('B*',pack('H*',$1))/egi;
$hash2 =~ s/([a-f0-9][a-f0-9])/unpack('B*',pack('H*',$1))/egi;

$count = ($hash1 ^ $hash2) =~ tr/\0//c;
```

Comment: Can you explain the code a little? The replacement `s///` seems unecessary. Also, you return the number of bits that are the same.

Comment: @nwellnhof The first two lines convert the hex to binary. How can that happen if there is not substitution?  I have added `/c` to return differences instead.