# How to compare two hex values in drools

Tags: hex, drools

I need to compare two hex values in `drools`.

for eg: compare `0xbadf00d` with `0xbadf00e`

This should result in false as `d` doesn't match with `e`.
So my question is, can hex be treated as string value and same comparisons can be made, or there is some other way.

I tried googling but no use.

Comment: What type are you currently using in your model to hold these values?

Comment: Actually it's a input from web page, which will be a json object, and be either converted into string or a long array.

Comment: Regarding the question you've deleted today: It is *not* necessary to post the *full project*. All you need is code sufficient to reproduce the issue. Yes, that may mean a little more work from *your* side than just a copy-paste of a few random lines - but don't expect me or others to do this work for you.

Comment: @laune absolutely right, but the main reason behind deleting was, that I got the alternative, and posting it as answer to the question would have confused many others :)

Comment: Alternative or no alternative - this isn't the point I'm addressing. Don't post a question unless the problem can be reproduced from what you post in the first place. It's just a waste of time - for you, for me and others.

Comment: @laune sure, will keep this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ASCII, the natural order of the [digits and letters of an HEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259681/compare-two-hex-strings-in-java) is ascending. This makes the comparison of these values as Strings trivial (assuming they are left-padded with 0s and using the same case).

As an example, if you have an `Input` class with a `hex` attribute of type `String` you can write something like this:

```
rule "Test"
when
    $i1: Input()
    $i2: Input(hex > $i1.hex)
then
    //Do whatever you need here
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Does it mean, I can use all the string function such as `substring()`, `isuppercase()` and others while comparing them?

Comment: I would suggest you to forget about Drools for a second and just focus on comparing the values in Java. Once you tested that the comparison is working as expected, then you can move to Drools.