# To check if hex string is in given range

Tags: java, string

I have hex string input . I want to write java program to check if given hex string is in the range of 90D00-90D39. 
Wether i should use stringCompareTO()?

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259681/compare-two-hex-strings-in-java

Comment: if I compare "903D5".compareTo("90D00"); I am getting -17 as output